# Time difference between 2 distinct events in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the time difference between 2 events in BigQuery (they are 2 customized events that we set up in Firebase). The first one is event_a, the second one is an event_b that is fired after event_a (no matter when).

I've tried with the following query:

```
SELECT round(AVG(time_diff),2) avg_duration_minutes
FROM(
SELECT user_pseudo_id,        
  CASE WHEN event_name = 'event_a' AND 
 LEAD(event_name,1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC) = 'event_b'
   THEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(LEAD(event_timestamp, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC)), TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), minute) END time_diff
FROM  `database`
WHERE event_name in ('event_a', 'event_b')
)
where time_diff > 0.2
```

Sample data:

```
user_pseudo_id   event      timestamp
aaa              event_a    1587995938387000
bbb              event_a    1590948191239003
aaa              event_b    1587995943075005
ccc              event_a    1589130017650008
aaa              event_a    1593078261900005
aaa              event_b    1593078881226002
bbb              event_b    1590948208425007
ccc              event_b    1589130462706020
```

The result that I would like to get is the average time between event_a and event_b per user and in total.

Do you have any suggestions? it would be important to know how much time occurs between 2 specific events (no matter when the second one occurs).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also "doesn't seem to be correct" is not helpful.  Describe the problem.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, can you provide sample data and desired output. So it is possible to write a query and test it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry it was the first time I used this website. Is it better now? I added a simple table with data that are similar to what I have in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  user_pseudo_id, 
  AVG(duration) AS avg_duration, 
  SUM(duration) AS total_duration
FROM (
  SELECT *, LEAD(timestamp) OVER(win) - timestamp AS duration
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE event IN ('event_a', 'event_b')
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY timestamp)

) 
WHERE event = 'event_a'
GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would answer like this:

```
with data as (
  select user_pseudo_id, event_name, event_timestamp from `database` where event_name in ('event_a', 'event_b')
),
ea as (
 -- Get first event_a per user
 select user_pseudo_id, min(event_timestamp) as first_a_ts from data where event_name = 'event_a' group by 1
),
eb as (
 -- Get first event_b per user
 select user_pseudo_id, min(event_timestamp) as first_b_ts from data where event_name = 'event_b' group by 1
),
joined (
  -- Assume we only want to calculate duration if user has an event_b, hence inner join
  select * 
  from ea 
  inner join eb using(user_pseudo_id) 
  where first_b_ts > first_a_ts
)
select 
  avg(timestamp_diff(first_b_ts, first_a_ts, second))/60.0 as avg_duration_minutes
from joined
```

I did not include your `.2` because I'm not sure why you are arbitrarily filtering out differences of less than 12 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the time of event b after event a, you can use a conditional cumulative minimum:

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM (SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp as event_a_timestamp,  
             MIN(CASE WHEN event_name = 'event_b' THEN event_timestamp END) OVER 
                 (PARTITION BY user_id 
                  ORDER BY event_timestamp  
                  ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                 ) as event_b_timestamp  
     FROM  `database`
     WHERE event_name in ('event_a', 'event_b')
    ) ab
WHERE event_name = 'event_a'
```

Your question doesn't provide enough details to determine what else might need to be done.